# Can we create additional uid/cn in Wso2 IS embedded Ldap

Tags: ldap, wso2, openldap, apache-directory, wso2-identity-server

I used ApacheDS to view the structure of the Domain & its children (New tenants).
But couldn't create any values on it.
**Below image depicts**
[image: Apache directory Wso2 IS 5.2.0]

I want to add uid/cn under each **domain[i].com** purpose is to just store some extra details about those domains.
Is that possible?

 if I add **uid**, it throws non-structural object exception.
if I add **ou**, it throws object doesn't exist!
Is that possible?

**Edit:** or either as a custom attribute for each users/ @domain[i].com level ?

Comment: Seems to be it not supported by ldap schema in apacheds. Its not a limitation introduced by WSO2. Embedded ldap in WSO2IS is just another apacheds loaded with identityPerson, scimPerson, and wso2Person schemas.

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena can we add custom attribues to the users created under ou=users?

Comment: You can add any attribute supported by the schema of the particular entry.

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena which means I can edit the existing schema/ have to create a new schema?